# Why Lithium-3 mass supposedly exceed hydrogen mass per nucleon?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, isotopes

When I check this [list of isotopes](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Compositions/stand_alone.pl?ele=&all=all&ascii=ascii&isotype=all) or even [this one](https://periodictable.com/Isotopes/001.1/index2.full.dm.html), I can find that the mass of lithium 3 per nucleon would be higher that the one of hydrogen, that is, the binding energy would be negative:

- Hydrogen: 1.00782503223 / 1 -> 1.00782503223
- Lithium-3: 3.0308 / 3 -> 1.0102667

I get the same strange results for Beryllium-5 or Boron-6.

What am I missing ? Are just the figures given in these links bad approximation of real mesurements? Or is it a theoretical mass, inferred from a *shaky* equation like the [semi-empirical mass formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula), which would be related to an atom that cannot actually exist?

*edit: added the division by 3 to clearly show the result is higher and rephrased the last sentence.*

Comment: That's not the mass per nucleon, that's the total mass. The two links also never say those numbers are the mass per nucleon; they both label them as the total mass. Also, if you have a question about the semi-empirical mass formula, ask a separate question about it; your assertion that the formula is "actually impossible" is either the starting material for another question or is irrelevant and should be removed from this one.

Comment: Google 'Atomic Mass Evaluation 2016' and look through the tables in part 2. Indeed, the binding energies of different nuclei are different.

Comment: @Jon Thanks to your hint, I could find from http://amdc.in2p3.fr/masstables/Ame2016/mass16.txt that data for 3Li is `(non-experimental) estimated values`, and that the binding energy computed is negative; this answer more or less my question.

Comment: Yeah, trying to stuff 3 protons together without any neutrons is going to be a problem...

Comment: Also, for light nuclei TUNL (http://www.tunl.duke.edu/nucldata/) is a great resource for energy level diagrams and reaction paths to different nuclei.